# typeset: not found error when executing shell script. Am I missing a package or something?

Tags: compiling, scripts

below is the error and corresponding script lines:

```
spec@Lucifer:~/Documents/seagull.svn.LINUX$ ./build.ksh
./build.ksh: 36: typeset: not found
./build.ksh: 39: typeset: not found
./build.ksh: 44: function: not found
Command line syntax of  - options
-exec <RELEASE|DEBUG>       : mode used for compilation (default RELEASE)
-target <all|clean|force|dist>    : target used for compilation (default all)
-help                       : display the command line syntax
./build.ksh: 52: function: not found
ERROR: 
spec@Lucifer:~/Documents/seagull.svn.LINUX$
```

**Script**

```
# Init of variables
BUILD_TARGET=${BUILD_DEFAULT_TARGET}
BUILD_EXEC=${BUILD_DEFAULT_EXEC}
typeset -u BUILD_OS=`uname -s | tr '-' '_' | tr '.' '_' | tr '/' '_' `
BUILD_CODE_DIRECTORY=code
BUILD_DIRECTORY=`pwd`
typeset -u BUILD_ARCH=`uname -m | tr '-' '_' | tr '.' '_' | tr '/' '_' `
BUILD_VERSION_FILE=build.conf
BUILD_DIST_MODE=0
BUILD_FORCE_MODE=0
```

Comment: Are you able to post the whole script or make it available somewhere? Sometimes it's non-obvious things like whitespace that messes up the interpreter so it's useful to have the whole thing intact to examine.

Comment: Here is a link to the script = http://silenceprohibitedrecordings.com/files/script.odt

Comment: What does this output? `/bin/ksh -c 'print ${.sh.version}'`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you are using the ksh (Korn SHell) shell (at least I have that suspect because of filename "build.ksh"). Note, that different shells have different syntaxes, I am not sure ksh does know "typeset" at all, I am not sure about this one, since I am not using ksh. However it would be nice to know what kind of shell you're using exactly. Please show us the first line of that "build.ksh" which starts with `#!`.

Comment: This was my suspicion also. But I installed ksh and tried it.

It seems that 'bash' and 'ksh' have <code>typeset</code> implemented. But 'sh' doesn't.

Is it possible that 'sh' rather than 'ksh' is being used [for some reason] to execute the command?

Comment: It is possible, I only assumed ksh because of the file name, but it seems that script is executable (and not run by "sh build.ksh" or so), so then it would be nice the #! line so you can see what shell is used.

Comment: Here is the full script. Actually the reference to Korn shell made me remember something. I had to remove the k from ksh at the beginning line before the script would actually execute:

Comment: http://silenceprohibitedrecordings.com/files/script.odt